# How to sign AWS API request in Java (for Android app)

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

How can I sign an AWS API request in Java? I was able to find how to do this in PHP but cannot seem to find anything in Java. I would like to sign a request to [ItemSearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html).

Is there maybe a library or something? (Note: I want to use this for Android).

Comment: Found a great resource here; http://mobilemerit.com/amazon-product-advertising-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Use the Java SDK. Unlike when using PHP, the Java library takes care of the signature for you automatically.

Example is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/ImplementinganA2SRequest.html

Comment: I am trying to use this in Android. Is the process the same?

Comment: I have not tried it with Android, but I would assume it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the AWS SDK for Android instead of trying to create requests manually.

Download: https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/ (Also supports Maven/Gradle)
Api docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/
Getting started:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/Welcome.html
GitHub:
-Source => https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android
-Samples => https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples

Answer (score 0):

AWS's SDKs provide various high-level clients for various services which automatically sign the requests.

However, if you're trying to sign an arbitrary request, you would most likely want to use the `Aws4Signer` class from the [Java SDK 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html). Here is an outline of using it to sign a `SdkHttpFullRequest` object, from which we can get the relevant headers.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> generateAwsSignedHeaders(String host, String path, String httpMethod, String body)
    // Replace this with the relevant AWS service name
    String serviceName = "foo";
    String region = "us-east-1";

    Aws4Signer signer = Aws4Signer.create();

    // In this example we directly create a ProfileCredentialsProvider but normally you should have
    // a DefaultCredentialsProvider that you reuse
    ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
    SdkHttpFullRequest request = SdkHttpFullRequest.builder()
            .encodedPath(path)
            .protocol("https")
            .method(SdkHttpMethod.valueOf(httpMethod))
            .contentStreamProvider(() -> SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(body).asInputStream())
            .host(host)
            // Add headers here, if you want/need them to be signed
            //.putHeader("", "")
            .build();

    // Some use cases might require configuring a SignerChecksumParams too
    Aws4SignerParams signerParams = Aws4SignerParams.builder()
            .awsCredentials(credentialsProvider.resolveCredentials())
            .signingName(serviceName)
            .signingRegion(Region.of(region))
            .build();
    
    credentialsProvider.close();

    // Sign the request
    SdkHttpFullRequest signedRequest = signer.sign(request, signerParams);
    
    // In this example, we just return the headers which includes headers added by the signer
    return signedRequest.headers();
}
```